# Вызов метода класса по его имени

Tags: c++

Я пытаюсь сделать что-то подобное

```
class Arguments {
        /* implimentation */
};

class Base {};

class One: public Base {
        private:
                int val;
        public:
                One(int val_): val(val_) {}
                Arguments test_one(Arguments args) {
                        printf("my int is: %d", val);
                        return Arguments("ok")
                };
};

class Two: public Base {
        private:
                std::string val2;
        public:
                Two(std::string val_): val2(val_) {};
                Arguments test_two(Arguments args) {
                        printf("my string is: %s", val2.c_str());
                        return Arguments("ok");
                };
};

std::map<std::string, Base*> components = {{"test1", new One(123)}, {"test2", new One(321)}, {"test3", new Two("test")}}

Arguments invoke(std::string comp, std::string name, Arguments args) {
        //getMethod?
        return components[comp]->getMethod(name)(args);
}

invoke("test1", "test_one", Arguments())
invoke("test2", "test_one", Arguments())
invoke("test3", "test_two", Arguments())
```

Функциия `invoke` должна принимать строку с ключём, который предоставляет доступ к какому-то классу, а вторая строка - это имя метода класса

Comment: Вам наверное надо использовать std::function/std::bind для связывание строки с конкретным методом класса.

Comment: Я делал `static std::map<std::string, std::map<std::string, funcpointer>>` но я хочу чтобы функция зависела от экземпляра класса

Comment: std::function/std::bind позволяет привязать метод к конкретному экземпляру класса. std::function/std::bind - это более гибкий подход, чем просто указатель на функцию.

Comment: `std::bind` это то, что мне нужно. А как можно генерировать эти функции в родительском классе при создании экземпляра дочернего? Я думаю сделать статичное поле `std::map<Base*, std::map<std::string, std::function...>>`, оно будет хранить созданные экземпляры и их функции... Но мне кажется можно лучше

Comment: в методах  test_one и test_two  аргумент наверное лишный